# Is it possible in Snakemake to have "optional" wildcard or part of the filename?

Tags: python, wildcard, snakemake

I wonder if it is possible to join these two rules in Snakemake in a single rule (they do the same in the "run:"):

```
rule without_d:
    input:
        vals_pca    = 'stats/input_{type}.npz',
    output:
        for_cnv     = 'stats/output_{type, tt|gs}.npz'
    run:
        # DO STUFF

rule with_d:
    input:
        vals_pca    = 'stats/input_{type}_d{amount}.npz',
    output:
        for_cnv     = 'stats/output_{type, tt|gs}_d{amount}.npz'
    run:
        # DO STUFF
```

I have tried to define `stats/output_{type}{amount}.npz`, but wildcards apparently do not match an empty string.
The second idea was to put it into "or" like `stats/{output, output_{type}|output_{type}_d{amount}}`, but here the problem is with a wildcard in a wildcard.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to Eric I realized that regular expressions can be used in snakemake rules' wildcards. The only problem is then that snakemake does not accept "empty" wildcards, but this can be overridden as explained in the post here: https://groups.google.com/g/snakemake/c/S7fTL4jAYIM?pli=1
Thus the solution to my problem is as follows:

```
rule both:
    input:
        vals_pca    = 'stats/input_{type}{amount}.npz',
    output:
        for_cnv     = 'stats/output_{type, tt|gs}{amount, .{0}|_d.+}.npz'
    run:
        # DO STUFF
```

Snakemake will match `{amount, .{0}|_d.+}` as an empty string or string beginning with `_d`.
Hope it will help somebody.

Answer (score 0):

Can't you do it the very simple way:

```
rule with_something:
    input:
        vals_pca    = 'stats/input_{something}.npz',
    output:
        for_cnv     = 'stats/output_{something}.npz'
    run:
        # DO STUFF
```

Wildcards are defined by the output files. If you ask for file `output_typeWhatever_dWhatever.npz` then the rule will look for `input_typeWhatever_dWhatever.npz`. If you ask for file `output_typeWhatever.npz` then the rule will use as input `input_typeWhatever.npz`.

Keep you rules as simple/generic as possible. Don't forget that snakemake resolves the wildcards from the final file you ask for and goes down the rules to see how to produce this file.

Comment: Thanks, Eric; I was thinking about it, but the problem of that solution is that then the rule will match any suffix to "output_", not only suffixes starting with accepted type. Or, assume we do not have the type, so outputs like: `output.npz` and `output_d{value}.npz` - your solution does not address that issue, since we cannot use `output{suffix}.npz` rule, because `{suffix}` will not match an empty string.

Comment: I suggest you use a specific pattern for each rule in your Snakefile. If all rules produce files like `stats/output_{suffix}.npz` then your workflow will be very confusing. In your question, you didn't address the case where `type` is an empty string. Moreover you can define more complex constraints like `{suffix, tt\w+|gs\w+}` (haven't tested these regex in constraints though). My solution will however address the `output_d{value}.npz` (without setting constraints) outputs. Maybe you should show the different suffix cases you might want in your question.